# Problematic conversion of phasor form of field in electromagnetic wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, vectors, maxwell-equations

## Edit (answer)

Although I do not have enough reputation to post a formal answer to the question, thanks to Mike Stone and Triatticus (see comments below), it became apparent that the issue was with differentiating eq. \eqref{1}. Specifically, by the chain rule:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}_s e^{j\omega t}}{\partial t} = j\omega \mathbf{E}_s e^{j\omega t}
$$

But when originally posting the question, I forgot the $e^{j\omega t}$ factor. Once this factor is accounted for, it cancels with its counterpart on the LHS of eq. \eqref{4}.

## Original question

I am stuck on a relatively simple step when analyzing electromagnetic wave equations in lossy media (for either $\mathbf{E}$ or $\mathbf{H}$). Specifically, the textbook that I am following [1] first proposes the following equation:

$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{E} = \sigma\mu \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t} + \mu\varepsilon\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2}
\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

The book then goes on to make the substitution $\mathbf{E}(x, y, z, t) = \mathbf{E}_s(x, y, z)e^{j\omega t}$, i.e., explicitly writing the electric field using its phasor form. The next step in the derivation is to perform differentiation on $\mathbf{E}$ on the right-hand side and simplify the Laplacian on the left. The book states the following:

$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{E}_s = j\omega\mu (\sigma + j\omega\varepsilon)\mathbf{E}_s
\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

### The problem

The RHS of the above equation is clear to me and I followed through that by evaluating $\partial \mathbf{E}/\partial t$, and so on. However, the Laplacian simplification puzzles me. Earlier in the book, it is made clear that the Laplacian is taken only with respect to the spatial coordinates $x, y, z$, i.e., not with respect to $t$.

Knowing this, my first step in verifying the book's derivation of eq. \eqref{2} was to write $\mathbf{E}$ as a phasor and then evaluate $\nabla^2 \mathbf{E}$:

$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{E} = \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}, \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right) \cdot \left( (\mathbf{E}_s)_x e^{j\omega t}, (\mathbf{E}_s)_y e^{j\omega t}, (\mathbf{E}_s)_z e^{j\omega t} \right)
\tag{3}\label{3}
$$

Because we aren't differentiating w.r.t. $t$, the exponential factor can be taken as a constant. However, according to this reasoning, the final simplification should be:

$$
e^{j\omega t}\nabla^2 \mathbf{E}_s
\tag{4}\label{4}
$$

and not

$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{E}_s
$$

### The question

Having read the above, could you perhaps suggest a way of explaining how eq. \eqref{2} was derived from eq. \eqref{1}? In addition, could you tell me if there are any fallacies with my line of thought, and how I could go around fixing them so that I could arrive at the correct result?

### References:

[1] Balaji, S. (2020). Electromagnetics Made Easy. Springer Singapore.

Comment: Really both of your last two equations are correct though in the right context. It is a little unclear what your actual issue is.

Comment: There are  $e^{i\omega t}$ factors  on *both* sides of the equation. Just cancel them.

Comment: Oh yeah, ok I see the subscripts now, Mike Stone has exactly the clarifying remark. It seems you didn't compute your time derivative entirely correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed forgot that differentiation using the chain rule would yield $e^{j\omega t}$ on the RHS as well... It is all clear now :)